# How to edit the "div id=SuiteBarTop" next to the SharePoint icon?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

I've given this an honest go for the past two hours and I'm at my wits end.

I want to edit the global nav bar at the top (next to the SharePoint text) and add my own icons/links that would be right next to the settings gear wheel icon.

The div id is the SuiteBarTop but I can't find it in the seattle.html master file. The image below will show you what I'm talking about. [image]

There doesn't appear to be a way for me to add code into the seattle.html master file that would allow me to input this. I know it's possible but I can't figure it out myself. I know how to target it using CSS and do a bunch of cool things but I want to physically add an icon/image that has a link to the orange bar.

For context, I'm using SharePoint Designer 2013. I've also found exactly where I want to edit using the dev tools via F12. And please ignore the "1". That was my attempt to visualize what was where in the seattle.html file.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: This isn't supported at all, just FYI.

Comment: Meaning I can't edit the code to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Meaning you shouldn't (it is fully unsupported in SPO and this will break often, on-prem that risk is lower). Look into using the Custom Tiles feature, instead (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-server-2016).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it, there is a way with JavaScript, If you are to put this in SharePoint online, I suggest you look at [SPFX Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension), that will run site collection wide (if you want) to inject a script.

I believe this snippet would work:

```
//with pure javascript using querySelector should be enough

//first you need to create an element
var customElement = document.createElement('div');

//initialize function on top on where you would want to call the function
function clickMe(){alert("I am Clicked!")}

//construct your html inside of your created element
customElement.innerHTML = `<div id="myID" onclick="clickMe()">Click Me</div>`;

//use query selector to search the element where you want to attach your div
var insertTo = document.querySelector('#SuiteBarTop');

//append your custom element
insertTo.parentNode.insertBefore(customElement , insertTo);
```

Just like this:

[image]

Let me know if it helps, Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Don't edit existing standard master pages. You can create copy of standard master page and customize it.

- Open SharePoint Designer, Create copy of seattle.master
- Edit newly created master page in advanced mode
- Find `<span class="ms-siteactions-root" id="siteactiontd">`
- Paste your html markup (div, span, etc.) right after closing  of previous element

[image]

- Go to Master pages gallery and Publish master page
- Go to Site settings -> Master page and choose newly created Master page
  [image]